# Rails - Register a user in stages. Starting with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, registration

I want to change my user registration. Instead of letting the users fill in all the details at once I would like the user to fill in only the username and bring him to the registration page with the username filled in and he has to add the rest of the details.

What I have now at my landingpage (basically copy of the new user page):

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Username" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-success btn-md  createbutton"%> 


<% end %>
```

My registration page is at registation_path

```
 <% provide(:title, 'Register') %>
<div class = "container center">
<body class ="formbody">
 <center><h1>Sign up</h1></center>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>



  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-success createbutton"%> 

</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
</body>
```

I would like the user to fill in the name in 1 form at the landing page and get redirected to the registration form with the name filled in.

edit: added the controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
 before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
 def new
  @user = User.new 
 end

 def index 
  @users = User.all
 end

def edit 
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
 flash.now[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
end

 def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
   if @user.save
     log_in @user
     flash.now[:success] = "Account Created Succesfully"
     redirect_to @user
   else
    render 'new'
    end
  end

def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
  store_location
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end



 # Confirms the correct user.
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
end

end
```

Comment: Also post the controller actions for these both forms specially for landing page form action to suggest a solution ?

Comment: Check out this if it helps to your need - https://github.com/schneems/wicked